# Unrecognized rule in lex on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex

I am attempting to have lex use echo to spit back out reserved words in a program but I continue to get the following errors:

```
    scanner.l:30: unrecognized rule
scanner.l:30: unrecognized rule
scanner.l:70: unrecognized rule
scanner.l:70: unrecognized rule
scanner.l:70: unrecognized rule
scanner.l:71: unrecognized rule
scanner.l:71: unrecognized rule
```

Below is my scanner code for lex:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h>  
#include "tokens.h"
%}


ws      [ \t\r\n]+
quoted      \".*\"
letter      [A-Za-z]
digit       [0-9]
word        {letter}+(\-{letter}+)?
number      {digit}+
punc        [,:;()] 
begin       { ECHO; }        
boolean     { ECHO; }    
else        { ECHO; }       
end     { ECHO; }       
endif       { ECHO; }         
function    { ECHO; }       
if      { ECHO; }       
is      { ECHO; }       
integer     { ECHO; }       
real        { ECHO; }       
returns     { ECHO; }          
then        { ECHO; }         

%%

{begin}             { return(begin); } 
{boolean}           { return(BOOLEAN); } 
{else}              { return(ELSE); }
{end}               { return(END); }
{endif}             { return(ENDIF); }   
{function}          { return(FUNCTION); }
{if}                { return(IF); }
{is}                { return(IS); }
{integer}           { return(INTEGER); }
{real}              { return(REAL); }
{returns}           { return(RETURNS); }   
{then}              { return(THEN); }   
"&&"                    { return(LOGOPAND); }                   
"||"                    { return(LOGOPOR); }                           
"!="                    { return(LOGOPNOT); }   
[ \t\n]                 ;
{ws}                    { ECHO; }                          
"<"                     { ECHO; return(RELOP); } 
"="                     { ECHO; return(RELOP); } 
"/="                    { ECHO; return(RELOP); } 
">"                     { ECHO; return(RELOP); } 
">="                    { ECHO; return(RELOP); } 
"<="                    { ECHO; return(RELOP); }
"*"                     { ECHO; return(MULTOP); } 
"/"                     { ECHO; return(MULTOP); }  
"+"                     { ECHO; return(ADDOP); }      
"-"                     { ECHO; return(ADDOP); }
"true"                  { ECHO; return(BOOLLITERAL); }          
"false"                 { ECHO; return(BOOLLITERAL); }  
{digit}                 { ECHO; return(I_LITERAL); } 
{digit}+"."{digit}*             { ECHO; return(R_LITERAL); } 
begins                  { ECHO; return(BEGINS); }  
{punc}                  { ECHO; return yytext[0]; }   
{quoted}            { ECHO; }
{word}              {toTitle(yytext, yyleng); }
{number}            { ECHO; }

%%

int main() {
yylex();
}
```

This is a token file I created for lex to use with the scanner:

```
#ifndef TOKENS_H
#define TOKENS_H

typedef enum Tokens {RELOP = 256, ADDOP = 257, MULTOP = 258, LOGOPNOT = 259, BOOLLITERAL = 260, I_LITERAL = 261, R_LITERAL = 262, IDENTIFIER = 263, PUNCTUATION = 264, BEGINS = 265, BOOLEAN = 266, ELSE = 267, END = 268, ENDIF = 269, FUNCTION = 270, IF = 271, IS = 272, INTEGER = 273, REAL = 274, RETURNS = 275, THEN = 276, LOGOPAND = 277, LOGOPOR = 278, begin = 279} Tokens;

#endif
```

Finally I have a case.c file to be used in conjunction with it all:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "tokens.h"

extern int yylex();
extern int yyleng();
extern int yylineno;
extern char* yytext;


void toTitle(char* yytext, int yyleng)
{
    putchar(toupper(yytext[0]));
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < yyleng; i++)
        putchar(toupper(yytext[i]));
}

int main()
{
    while (yylex());
    return 0;
}
```

Why would I be getting these errors?  I'm sure it is simple.
Thanks.

Comment: That lex file looks like it was pasted together from random snippets using different styles. If you want to learn flex, you'd be better off reading through the `flex` manual and following along with the examples. Start with the simple example in section 4, and then maybe take a look at: http://sourceforge.net/p/flex/flex/ci/master/tree/examples/manual/pascal.lex. In general terms, it is neither necessary nor useful to create a definition for every pattern, and it is not necessary to quote patterns consisting only of letters and numbers (see the examples for examples).

Comment: LOL!  Well this is what I actually built so far and I am completely new to lex.  I didn't just grab snippets using different styles but since I'm totally new to lex and C it probably looks pretty bad.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says: the error is in line 30, in the definitions section, where you define your tokens.

```
 begin       { ECHO; }
```

If you replace this by some meaningful token definition - maybe "begin" - , you will get the same error message for the equivalent definitions that follow.

ECHO is a special statement, that can only be used in the actions section.

see http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/manpage.html

Comment: Thanks!  I rectified the code by moving all the reserved words and their actions to the first part before the %% syntax so:

   is  { ECHO; return(IS); }  
integer  { ECHO; return(INTEGER); }  
real  { ECHO; return(REAL); }  
returns  { ECHO; return(RETURNS); }     
then  { ECHO; return(THEN); }    

%%
  
"&&"              { return(LOGOPAND); }                   
"||"              { return(LOGOPOR); }                           
"!="              { return(LOGOPNOT); }   
[ \t\n]           ;
{ws}              { ECHO; }