# Lex analyzer for generating file not producing a listing of program with lexical error messages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex

I am attempting to build a lex analyzer that produces a listing of the program with lexical error messages included after the line in which they occur.  In other words if the character read cannot start a token it is considered an error.  It is also supposed to generate a file with the lexeme-token pairs so that it can verify that the analyzer is working.  I can get an output file but it is not working correctly as when I attempt to run it it just gives me a command screen like I'm inside the file working.  Here is my code for my scanner file that reads an input text:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h>  
#include "tokens.h"

void toTitle(char* yytext, int yyleng);
%}

%option noyywrap 

ws      [ \t\r\n]+
quoted      \".*\"
letter      [A-Za-z]
digit       [0-9]
word        {letter}+(\-{letter}+)?
number      {digit}+
punc        [,:;()] 
begin       { ECHO; return(begin);}  
boolean     { ECHO; return(BOOLEAN);}    
else        { ECHO; return(ELSE); }     
end     { ECHO; return(END); }      
endif       void toTitle(char* yytext, int yyleng){ ECHO; return(ENDIF); }        
function    { ECHO; return(FUNCTION); }     
if      { ECHO; return(IF); }       
is      { ECHO; return(IS); }       
integer     { ECHO; return(INTEGER); }      
real        { ECHO; return(REAL); }     
returns     { ECHO; return(RETURNS); }         
then        { ECHO; return(THEN); }
line        [\n]  

%%

"&&"                    { return(LOGOPAND); }                   
"||"                    { return(LOGOPOR); }                           
"!="                    { return(LOGOPNOT); }   
[ \t\n]                 ;
{ws}                    { ECHO; }                          
"<"                     { ECHO; return(RELOP); } 
"="                     { ECHO; return(RELOP); } 
"/="                    { ECHO; return(RELOP); } 
">"                     { ECHO; return(RELOP); } 
">="                    { ECHO; return(RELOP); } 
"<="                    { ECHO; return(RELOP); }
"*"                     { ECHO; return(MULTOP); } 
"/"                     { ECHO; return(MULTOP); }  
"+"                     { ECHO; return(ADDOP); }      
"-"                     { ECHO; return(ADDOP); }
"true"                  { ECHO; return(BOOLLITERAL); }          
"false"                 { ECHO; return(BOOLLITERAL); }  
{digit}                 { ECHO; return(I_LITERAL); } 
{digit}+"."{digit}*             { ECHO; return(R_LITERAL); } 
begins                  { ECHO; return(BEGINS); }  
{punc}                  { ECHO; return yytext[0]; }   
{quoted}            { ECHO; }
{word}              {toTitle(yytext, yyleng); }
{number}            { ECHO; }

%%

void toTitle(char* yytext, int yyleng)
{

}

void tokenCount(int token)
{
    while (token = yylex())
        fprintf(yyout, "%d %s\n", token, yytext);
}

int main() {
while (yylex());
    return 0;

}
```

I have a header file with my defined tokens:

```
#ifndef TOKENS_H
#define TOKENS_H

typedef enum Tokens {RELOP = 256, ADDOP = 257, MULTOP = 258, LOGOPNOT = 259, BOOLLITERAL = 260, I_LITERAL = 261, R_LITERAL = 262, IDENTIFIER = 263, PUNCTUATION = 264, BEGINS = 265, BOOLEAN = 266, ELSE = 267, END = 268, ENDIF = 269, FUNCTION = 270, IF = 271, IS = 272, INTEGER = 273, REAL = 274, RETURNS = 275, THEN = 276, LOGOPAND = 277, LOGOPOR = 278, begin = 279} Tokens;

#endif
```

My output is supposed to look something like this:

```
   1  -- Simple program with one function
   2
   3  function main a: integer returns integer;
   4      b: integer is a * 2;
   5  begin
   6      if a <= 0 then
   7          b + b;
   8      else
   9    b * b;
  10      endif;
  11  end;

Compiled Successfully
```

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that this is third question you've asked on the same problem and suspect that you might not be fully understanding how to complete this task or the documentation and answers you've seen so far.  Stackoverflow has guidance and standards on the best ways of forming a question to get the best value and service from the many world class experts available here, such as this [guidance on asking questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I see that you might be a beginner at this, and in the case of your problem it would have been to your advantage to learn [how to simplify the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'll demonstrate how you could simplify the problem, using your code as an example, and thus arrive at a good description of the problem and eventually the solution.

The problem with your code, is the same problem identified in comments by @rici to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143517/unrecognized-rule-in-lex-on-ubuntu-14-04) "That lex file looks like it was pasted together from random snippets using different styles".

Let's go back to the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) and look at the overall structure of a flex program:

```
     definitions
     %%
     rules
     %%
     user code
```

The position of the `%%` lines divide the code into three sections, and thus what you put before the `%%` and what you put after `%%` is really **important**.

Now in the answer to your last question @nlu wrote:

> ECHO is a special statement, that can only be used in the actions section.

and then you replied:

> I rectified the code by moving all the reserved words and their actions to the first part before the `%%` syntax

Unfortunately you misread that suggestion and left code for the rules/action section in the declaration section. Unfortunately this did not cause flex to give you any helpful messages, as it remained a meaningful flex program; just not the one you were expecting!

To clarify, you cannot have any actions, including an `ECHO`, before the first `%%`, because then it would be in the definitions section. They must be **after** the first `%%` so the are in the rules/actions section. So, as a consequence, all these lines are in the wrong place:

```
begin       { ECHO; return(begin);}  
boolean     { ECHO; return(BOOLEAN);}    
else        { ECHO; return(ELSE); }     
end     { ECHO; return(END); }      
endif       void toTitle(char* yytext, int yyleng){ ECHO; return(ENDIF); }        
function    { ECHO; return(FUNCTION); }     
if      { ECHO; return(IF); }       
is      { ECHO; return(IS); }       
integer     { ECHO; return(INTEGER); }      
real        { ECHO; return(REAL); }     
returns     { ECHO; return(RETURNS); }         
then        { ECHO; return(THEN); }
```

How could you have debugged this on your own? As its suggests in the SO help pages: **simplify**. I'll demonstrate by example how that could be done. If you reduced the problem to a language with only one keyword, lets says `begin` and some whitespace, and deleted all the other lines, for all the other keywords and symbols, then there would be a much simpler problem to address. Lets try this with your code:

```
%option noyywrap 

ws      [ \t\r\n]+    
begin       { ECHO; return(begin);} 
line        [\n]
%%
[ \t\n]                 ;
{ws}                    { ECHO; }  
begins                  { ECHO; return(BEGINS); } 
%%

int main() {
while (yylex());
return 0;
}
```

You will note I have just deleted all the lines that relate to other keywords and symbols as they are confusing the picture with a jumble of extra lines. This is exactly what expert and professional programmers do in their day to day problem solving. You don't think we have some psychic way of finding bugs do  you? :-) This is the skill that comes with practise.

Now, focussing on this **simpler** program, there are things we can see. It does compile and run by the way, and its all your code (just simpler). If we run it, the keyword `begins` gets `ECHO`ed but the keyword `begin` does not. There is a clue there. If the line for `begin` was moved to below the `%%` it would work just as the `begins` line did. But why did flex accept the bad program and not give you a helpful error? This is because that line is still a **valid definition** of a lexeme according to flex regular expression notation. What you defined was a lexeme called `begin` (which you access using the notation `{begin}` in the rules section) which is defined as matching the **string** `"{ ECHO; return(begin);}"`. However, as you never typed that string, and also never used the name `{begin}` that fragment of definition never gets used.

There is also the question: Does your language really have a keyword called `begin` and another one called `begins`. Seems fishy to me. Another bug perhaps?
Similarly we cans see the same with the white space. You have tried to match a newline `\n` in three places. This is going to be confusing, as you cannot be sure which of the definitions and actions flex will perform when encountering a newline. As you want to number the lines at some point this might be a problem for you. You've also told it to both ignore and `ECHO` whitespace. Which is it to be? It cannot do both. From your example output, perhaps you wanted them echoed. Making all these fixes to the **simple** program we get this:

```
%option noyywrap 

ws                      [ \t\r]+  
line                    [\n]    
%%
{ws}                    { ECHO; }  
begin                   { ECHO; return(BEGIN); } 
%%

int main() {
while (yylex());
return 0;
}
```

which works for a simple language with only the keyword `begin`. All we now have to do is put the other bits back in, slowly and carefully. Next, lets add the keyword `endif` to the code, and we get:

```
%option noyywrap 

ws                      [ \t\r]+  
line                    [\n]    
%%
{ws}                    { ECHO; }  
begin                   { ECHO; return(BEGIN); } 
endif       void toTitle(char* yytext, int yyleng){ ECHO; return(ENDIF); }
%%

int main() {
while (yylex());
return 0;
}
```

However, this **does not compile**. The piece of code `void toTitle(char* yytext, int yyleng)` looks like an erroneous paste, when you were hacking the code together from other peoples solutions -- *doh!*.

Now, that has dealt with all the faults in your code, and if you understood them you could get all your code working. Now, there is a bit more programming to do before you have completed the whole assignment. You need to add line counting, handling of variables and constants, and a few other bits and then you are done.

I hope you found that helpful, and leads to you being able to solve the rest of your coding exercise.